# How should I write my form action path in PHP when the directory can change from server to server?

Tags: php, http, smtp

I have this form:

```
       <form id="main-form" action="../path/php/handle_contact_form.php" method="post">
            <input class="form-holder name" name="input-name" type="text" placeholder="Name...">
            <input class="form-button" name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Contact us.">
        </form>
```

Which is handled by `handle_contact_form.php`.

Thing is, that path for **the action works for me, locally.**  But once I upload it to another server, suddenly, the path changes to: `/home/flowerp/public_html`.

My concern is that: no matter what, I always have to change the path on a per-install basis and that I'm also giving away my absolute path of the server.

My folder structure is as such:

```
assets
js
php
    -htmlpurifier
    -handle_contact_form.php
index.html
```

And I'm calling the php post action from `index.html`.

What are the solutions here?

Comment: Use a variable. Possibly read from the environment.

Comment: You should also be using a URL in the form not a path, mainly for security as is one of your issues that you mentioned.

Comment: @GlenElkins Great advice, any reading on that?

Comment: @redlagoon you can literally just put the full url in. It all depends on where your handle_contact_form.php file is. Is it in the public folder where the site is? If not it will be a little more difficult to explain